# "Manage isn't accessible via model Instances" error on template rendering

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a model namely President and there is list() on views.py:

```
from .models import President

def list(request):
    return render(request, 'president/list.html', {'President': President})
```

The following is list.html:

```
{% for p in President.objects.all %}
<li>{{p}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

But the error "Error during template rendering: Manager isn't accessible via President Instances." occurs.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access [manager methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#managers) in `Template`. You need to pass the queryset:

```
return render(request, 'president/list.html', {'president': President.objects.all()})
```

And use it in template:

```
{% for p in president %}
<li>{{p}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```